# Haskell: test if list contains specific "sublist"

Tags: list, search, haskell, substring, sublist

Is there a trick or a prelude function to test if a list contains a specific substring/sublist?

```
xyz :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
xyz "hello world" "worl" -> True
xyz [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5] [7,8,1] -> True
```

I tried to write one on my own, but this is a trivial problem and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: lmhtfy: http://haskell.org/hoogle/?q=[a]+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+Bool

Comment: Is it intentional that in the first case you're using `xyz` as if its type were `[a] -> [a] -> Bool` and in the second case as if it were `[[a]] -> [a] -> Bool`? Because it'd be pretty hard to find a function that allows both usages.

Comment: I just would like to add to dave4420's answer that you can find those functions via [hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Bool) (isInfixOf is the first hit).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`isInfixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isInfixOf) from Data.List.

The parameters are the other way round from what you asked for --- it's usually most readable to use the function like this: `` "worl" `isInfixOf` "hello world" `` (returns True).